# CMS для киностудии

Tags: cms

Есть киностудия, состоящая из студентов. Всё бесплатно и радостно. Но сайт мы подняли на joomla - посему приходится каждую статью одинаково оформлять чтобы смотрелось.
Существует ли CMS для киностудий или что-либо такое ?
То, что сейчас - [rgrtu.tv](http://rgrtu.tv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Большинство CMS, особенно бесплатных, и на столько глобальных, ориентированно на максимально большую аудиторию, то есть, чтобы и личную страницу могли сделать, и чтобы портал могли на нем завести, по этому её делают универсальной, а собственное оформление единицы записи, это как рас свобода действия.

Если вы хотите чтобы у вас был набор полей в админке, при заполнении которых у вас все красиво отображалось, не было ничего лишнего, и в админке было все придельно понятно и новичку, вам необходимо: либо качественно переделать ваш joomla шаблон, и админку, (как пришлось бы переделывать любую CMS) или же написать собственный двиг, где вы уже сами пропишите, и по умолчанию отформатируете все так как вам хотелось бы.

Для вашей задачи предполагаю, что оптимальным было бы первый вариант.